# connect to MySQL server from another network

Tags: mysql, networking, server, remote-access

evening,

I want to talk to my mysql server from other wifi/distant location but im quite a beginner and having hard time figuring out how this all works/how to do it.

i was using my 192.168... i know I should here use ip I got from typing my ip into webrowser :D ... is there way to get it from cmd on windows? I didnt find it there (using ipconfig)

but i guess i need to do more than just write this ip into mysql connection? there is more computers on this network. with website hosting, you need to do something like tell router to send traffic that is meant for website to send to certain computer as far as i know. i do something similiar here i would guess?

im using xampp control panel to host it.

i know about setting up account in mysql server to allow access to database to someone remote, im asking more about networking stuff. im newbie so there may be some, you know, misunderstandings about this stuff in my question.

to sum it up- im curious about networking part of setting up mysql server and making it accessible not just from local network (i guess its called local network?)

thanks for any advice :)

Comment: The `sql-server` tag is for Microsoft SQL Server. Could you indicate how MSSQL is involved with your problem or remove the tag?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning what do you think?

Comment: Making services accessible to the public internet at large will cause a large number of bored people to keep hammering away at it trying to get a successful login. Consider alternatives such as making an SSH tunnel into the MySQL server's network, or use a VPN connection.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you very much :) i didnt think about vpn's in this way until today :D i definitely try this approach ...i didnt know sql-server is for microsoft sql s :)